# Streaming vs linking static files

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for advantages of streaming over just linking static files, eg images, pdf.

To make question more clear, using node we can stream files using

```
fs.createReadStream
```

I can understand streaming videos etc but why should we stream static files. Where we can simply provide a href?

Answer (score 0):

If your static files are already available on some URL then there's no need to stream them using Node. If your Node app wants to return the contents of a static file that is already hosted and served somewhere then instead of streaming its contents it can simply return a redirect with the file's URL.

Comment: You can always configure static assets on any server but is there any advantage of streaming these files instead? Thanks

Comment: @RuntimeException When you set up static assets ans serve them using express.static in Node or with nginx then that's what happens: they are streamed to the client. You can stream those files in Node manually or you can leave it to nginx or express.static to stream it for you. The files are streamed in both cases.